# How to match first group of match in regex with python

Tags: python, regex

Using python I want to find the first year in a copyright statement. So, for example, if the content is

```
content = "Copyright 2010-2020 MyCompany"
```

and my regex is as follows:

```
REGEX = re.compile(r"(COPYRIGHT).+(\d{4}).+", re.I)
```

I expect the second group to be 2010, but it is 2020. Complete code:

```
content = "Copyright 2010-2020 MyCompany"
REGEX = re.compile(r"(COPYRIGHT).+(\d{4}).+", re.I)
m = REGEX.match(line)
print(m.group(2))
```

I guess the regex matched the most-right match. How to make it match the first match it finds?

What I expect is that the second match matches the year "2010" instead.

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/GwAAwF/1 or https://regex101.com/r/GwAAwF/2

Answer (score 0):

Use the ungreedy `?`

```
(COPYRIGHT).?(\d{4}).+
```

Comment: No idea what"greedy" means

Comment: "greedy" means `.` matches as many characters as possible, "ungreedy" will match just few enough to meet the regex pattern.

Comment: Another synonym for `ungreedy` is `lazy`.